# Getting the column position in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Bacon</th>
     <th>Tuna</th>
     <th>Padas</th>
     <th>Another</th>
     <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

How can I get the column position after the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   bla..bla
});
```

The output would be `bacon = 0, tuna = 1 padas = 2` and so on...

Comment: Though I had revised the answer of @Michael Nguyen, he got what I am trying to figure out and I come to this,

    `column = [];
    $counter = -1;
    $("table th").each(function(){
    column.push($(this).text() + " = " + ++$counter);
    });
   alert(column);`

Thank you for the idea guys.

Comment: no worries, i wouldn't have minded making a new solution if you wanted an array filled with each header :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $counter = -1;
    $("table th").each(function(){
       document.write($(this).text() + " = " + ++$counter);
    });
});
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var columns = new Array();
    $('table tr th').each(function(idx) {
        columns[idx] = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    });

    // do what you need to do with your columns array here.  eg:
    for(var i = 0;i < columns.length;i++)
     document.write(columns[i] + ',');

});
```

**Example** here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Nzhu/1/

**Note**: you should give your table an id and change the selector above to '#mytableid tr th'

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map`:

```
var mapping = {};

$('table th').map(function(elem, index) {
    mapping[$(elem).text().toLowerCase()] = index;
});
```

Although this depends entirely on what you're trying to do with that data.